# Why do KDE Wallet Service keeps asking for password after changing user password?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, kwallet

I recently changes my user password using the command `passwd`, and then after I restarted the system and logged in using my newly set password, I started getting the annoying popups asking me to insert my **KDE Wallet Service** **password**, also my **Wifi password** was gone, and this popup showed every time I started **Google Chrome**, I tried both my old and current password, however non would seem to work, the only way I was able to get rid of the annoying popups in by reverting to my old password!

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this issue and change my user login password?

I have Kubuntu 17.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was able to get rid of the popups, however this has a side affect. Note that if you use this solution that you will lose any saved password in the system, e.g. **Wifi, Google Chrome users,...etc.** however you can always save them again.

Solution: delete, rename or move KDE Wallet Service folder which will create automatically a new fresh wallet

```
mv ~/.local/share/kwalletd ~/.local/share/kwalletd.old
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after changing the password for my account on Kubuntu 18.04. And, issue was KDE wallet still used the previous password. So, I provided the old password and changed it to the new password.